# How to specify arguments and return types for functions within functions using the Erlang Dialyzer?

Tags: types, functional-programming, erlang, erlang-otp, dialyzer

How do you specify arguments and return types type for functions within functions using the Erlang Dialyzer, such as functions from libraries or `Behavior` (e.g `gen_server`s `gen_server:reply/2`). For instance in the MVR code provided below, how can I specify that the `maps:put/3` gets the right order of arguments, such that it's thrird argument is a `map()` ?

Furthermore is there a way to ensure it for variables within a function and/or globally, such that for instance an integer I declare within a function gets `integer()`?

```
-module(example_module).

-export([my_function/1, state_changer/3, test_function/0]).

-type map_arg() :: #{key1 => integer(), key2 => atom()}.
-type move() :: rock | paper | scissor.
-type playersmap() :: #{players => {pid(), pid()}} | #{players => {pid(), pid()}, fst_mover => {{pid(),_}, move()}}.


-spec my_function(Map_arg :: map_arg()) -> ok.

my_function(Map) ->
    ok.

test_function() ->
    CorrectMap = #{key1 => 1, key2 => 'value'},
    IncorrectMap = #{key1 => 1, key2 => 2},
    my_function(CorrectMap),
    my_function(IncorrectMap),
    state_changer({move, rock}, {self(), tag}, #{players  => {self(), self()}, fst_mover => {{self(), tag}, scissor}}).

-spec state_changer({move, Choice :: move()}, From :: {pid(), _}, PlayersMap :: playersmap()) -> {reply, playersmap()}.
state_changer({move, Choice}, From, PlayersMap) ->        
    {CurId, _} = From,    
    {P1Id, P2Id} = maps:get(players, PlayersMap),
    case CurId of
        P1Id ->                        
            PlayersMapNew = maps:put(fst_mover, {From, Choice}, PlayersMap),                    
            {reply, PlayersMapNew};
        P2Id -> 
            PlayersMapNew = maps:put(fst_mover, {From, Choice}, PlayersMap),                    
            {reply, PlayersMapNew}
    end.
```

**EDIT**

So far the only thing I have been able to come up with is some sort of wrapper around the functions that I would like to declare some type specificity for. Such as `-spec my_maps_put(From :: reference(), Choice :: move(), PlayersMap :: playersmap())-> PlayersMapNew :: playersmap()` , but I don't know if this is the best way.

Comment: The functions in the standard library already have type specs, so if you pass something to `maps:put` that Dialyzer can prove isn't a map, you'll get a warning. Or is it something else you're looking for?

Comment: That is what I am asking about, but it is not my impression that dialyzer will catch these, since you cannot put in `-spec ... ` within a function, and the standard library doesn't specify what is comprised of as a key in `maps:put` if you want to make sure that the type you are feeding it as a key, is of a specific type, such as 'string'.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Would you get the behaviour you want from Dialyzer if you use map expressions to update the maps, e.g. `PlayersMapNew = PlayersMap#{fst_mover => {From, Choice}}`?

Comment: The quick syntax you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It seems like that would provide type checks at least in some cases.